# Jquery .val() is not changing anything on ui-autocomplete select handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an input with a jquery-ui autocomplete. On the autocomplete "select" function I want to change the input value to the selected item of the autocomplete. I have to do so because my data structure is different than the one expected by jquery-ui. Everything works fine but when I try to set the input value nothing changes, and I don't get any error.

Here it is my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="from" name="location" id="search-form-location" class="inputAddon-field flex-shrinker flex-grower" value="London, United Kingdom">
```

JS:

```
$( "#search-form-location" ).autocomplete({
  source: "/api/airports-autosuggest",
  minLength: 3,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ui.item,0,4));
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).val(ui.item.PlaceName);
  }
}).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  if (item.PlaceId===item.CityId){
    return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<span class='placeName'>"+ item.PlaceName +"</span> <span class='placeCode'>(All airports)</span> <span class='countryName'> " + item.CountryName +  "</span>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
  } else
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<span class='placeName'>" + item.PlaceName + "</span> <span class='placeCode'>("+trump(item.PlaceId, "-sky" )+")</span> <span class='countryName'>" + item.CountryName + "</span> " )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

When I select one option from the autocomplete console.log(JSON.stringify(ui.item,0,4)) prints out the object I'm expecting (e.g. below), console.log($(this)) prints the right object, but the input field become blank and shows just the placeholder. If I inspect it in the browser I still see the original value attr: value="London, United Kingdom"

ui.item object:

```
 {
    "PlaceId": "LOND",
    "PlaceName": "London",
    "CountryId": "UK",
    "RegionId": "",
    "CityId": "LOND",
    "CountryName": "United Kingdom"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `select` handler will overwrite your custom value. Add a `return false` to prevent the event handling logic from propagating to it:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ui.item,0,4));
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).val(ui.item.PlaceName);
    return false;
  }
```

Fiddle example out of http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/: http://jsfiddle.net/2qp708zo/